# How to plot geom_line features in ggplot2 map?

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, raster, spatial

I want to plot rivers (lines) in a map containing polygons (counties, etc) from South Dakota.  The river data is here, https://www.weather.gov/gis/Rivers.  Use the subset of rivers data set.  The county download can be obtained from here, https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2020/COUNTY/.

I only want the rivers that lie within the county boundaries of South Dakota, so I am using rgeos::intersection to perform that, which produces a Large SpatialLines object, which ggplot2 doesn't like when I try to plot it with geom_line (I get an error that says "Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S4 object with class SpatialLines.")

Here is my code:

```
library(rgdal)
library(raster)

counties <- readOGR('D:\\Shapefiles\\Counties\\tl_2020_us_county.shp')
counties <- counties[which(counties$STATEFP == '46'),]
counties <- spTransform(counties, CRS("+init=epsg:3395"))

rivers <- readOGR('D:\\Shapefiles\\Main_Rivers\\rs16my07.shp')
proj4string(rivers) <- CRS("+proj=longlat")
rivers <- spTransform(rivers, CRS("+init=epsg:3395"))
rivers <- as.SpatialLines.SLDF(rgeos::gIntersection(counties, rivers))
```

The raster packages "intersect" function does not work for doing the intersection.  I think I need to change the SpatialLines object to a spatialLinesDataFrame object to get ggplot2 to plot the rivers.  How do I do that?  The as.SpatialLines.SLDF function is not doing it.  Is there another way to get this to plot?  My plotting code is here:

```
ggplot() +
geom_path(counties, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group, col = 'darkgreen')) +
geom_path(rivers, mapping = aes(x = long, y = lat, color = 'blue'))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend handling your spatial data with the `sf` library. Firstly, it plays well with `ggplot`. Also, according to my very much infant understanding of GIS and spatial data in R, I believe that the idea is the `sf` will eventually take over from `sp` and the `Spatial*` data formats. `sf` is I think a standard format across multiple platforms. See [this link](https://r-spatial.github.io/sf/articles/sf1.html) for more details on `sf`.

Onto your question - this is quite simple using `sf`. To find the rivers inside a specific county, we use `st_intersection()` (the `sf` version of `gIntersection`).

```
library(sf)

# read in the rivers data
st_read(dsn = 'so_data/rs16my07', layer = 'rs16my07') %>%
  {. ->> my_rivers}

# set the CRS for the rivers data
st_crs(my_rivers) <- crs('+proj=longlat')

# transform crs
my_rivers %>% 
  st_transform('+init=epsg:3395') %>% 
  {. ->> my_rivers_trans}
  


# read in counties data
st_read(dsn = 'so_data/tl_2020_us_county') %>% 
  {. ->> my_counties}

# keep state 46
my_counties %>% 
  filter(
    STATEFP == 46
  ) %>% 
  {. ->> state_46}

# transform crs
state_46 %>% 
  st_transform('+init=epsg:3395') %>% 
  {. ->> state_46_trans}


# keep only rivers inside state 46
my_rivers_trans %>% 
  st_intersection(state_46_trans) %>% 
  {. ->> my_rivers_46}
```

Then we can plot the `sf` objects using `ggplot` and `geom_sf()`, just like you would plot lines using `geom_line()` etc. `geom_sf()` seems to know if you are plotting point data, line data or polygon data, and plots accordingly. It is quite easy to use.

```
# plot it
state_46_trans %>% 
  ggplot()+
  geom_sf()+
  geom_sf(data = my_rivers_46, colour = 'red')
```

Hopefully this looks right - I don't know my US states so have no idea if this is South Dakota or not.

[image]